# msysgit on the command prompt without bash

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-agent, msysgit

I've got mysysgit setup with Tortoise with PuTTY and ssh. From the Tortoise side everything is working I can clone, pull, push, etc. If I drop to a command prompt and run `git` I see the help screen so its in the path. When I go to a checked out git repository and issue a `git pull` it prompts me for a password for git@git.server.com. My understanding is that ssh failed at that point.

I know PuTTY is not the ssh program used on the command prompt. but I setup my keys. in 'c:\Users\username.ssh\' I have both a username_rsa and a username_rsa.pub. They are what I used to create the `ppk` for putty.

So I see there is some ssh-agent.exe and ssh-add.exe thing. I'm not using bash though. Bash is not installed and I have no desire to install it. How can I get Git working from the command prompt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use PuTTY, set the `GIT_SSH` environment variable to the path of `plink.exe` in the PuTTY directory.

```
set GIT_SSH="C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe"
```

`setx` can be used to make the variable permanent.